# Intellij idea 2016 invalid incompatible type

Tags: intellij-idea-2016

Intellij idea reports a compile error: incompatible types. However the groups variable on the left of that equation is defined exactly as com.example.intepipe.model.Groups. I have already tried invalid caches and restart

[image]

Comment: I believe you've typed `Groups` at some point in your code, then pressed Alt+Enter; Enter to add automatic import and wrong class was imported. Consider checking imports in this file manually.

Comment: @yeputons The interesting thing is after I fix compile errors in the other classes, this report of intellij idea is gone.